# Access an external file in Codename One

Tags: codenameone, external, filechooser

I want to play an audio that is in a WhatsApp folder. Is it possible with codename one to access images and audios that are in another application? I know there are other applications that can do it but in Codename One I can only access .cn1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

Mobile OSs force you to "stay in your lane" so you have no access to other applications or their files. This is core to mobile OSs and true for native code.

However, you can click the file in whatsapp and share it with your app and in that case you can use [this article](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/associating-your-app-with-file-extension-mime-types-iphone-android-windows.html) to include your app in that list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had read that it was not possible. But I can't understand why there are applications that can do it, for example:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.statusdownloader.whatsappstatussaver&hl=es_419&gl=US

Comment: There are three ways this app can work on Android. 1. They can access whatsapp specific configurations published by the app. 2. They can use very high level permissions to scan whatsapp. 3. They can rely on the fact that whatsapp saves things to a common location. Also they can rely on the whatsapp REST API and work against their server. All of those are very specific to whatsapp and Android so I'm guessing here. You will need to investigate that and take to consideration that a change to either might break your app.